# Python3 code that reformats file names

Tags: regex, python-3.6, macos-sierra

```
# Regex pattern
filePattern = re.compile(r'''
    (#LPy3THW_Ex)
    (\d){1,3}
    (_macOS|_Windows)?
    (\.mp4)
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

I am writing a program that is supposed to simplify "LPy3THW_Ex6.mp4" to "ex6.mp4". When I run it, below is the error message. I'm not sure what the problem is and how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_rename.py", line 13, in <module>
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 768, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2 (line 2, column 2)
```

Comment: Escape the `#`. `#LPy3THW_Ex` > `\#LPy3THW_Ex`. Else, it is treated as a comment. Or, if there is no `#` in the input, remove it. `LPy3THW_Ex6.mp4` has no hash at the start. Why did you add it to the regex pattern?

Comment: Also, why not use `s.split('_', 2)[-1].lower()`? Do you need that validation stuff?

Comment: Yes, the split method is much simpler and the code works now. Thank you! What does the [-1] do in s.split('_', 2)[-1].lower()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current error is due to the `#` symbol that starts an inline comment inside a regex pattern that is compiled with `re.VERBOSE` option.

You should escape it (if `#` should be present in the string as a literal hash char) or remove it (if the symbol is not expected inside the string in that context). Also, acc. to the sample input/output, you should remove `#` and rearrange the capturing groups, maybe something like:

```
filePattern = re.compile(r'''^
    LPy3THW_
    (
      Ex\d{1,3}
      (?:_macOS|_Windows)?
      \.mp4
    )
    $''', re.VERBOSE)
print(filePattern.sub(r"\1", s).lower())
# => ex6.mp4
```

Note that `(\d){1,3}` creates a repeated capturing group and only stores the last digit in the group. I added anchors to match the whole string, just for the demo purpose (since I am using `re.sub` here).

However, it seems you may just split with `_` into 2 parts and get the last item:

```
s.split('_', 2)[-1].lower() # => ex6.mp4
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/EKNLPD62569)